# How install Mozart 1.4.0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, development

I need the instructions for installing Mozart Programming System on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What's Mozart??

Comment: Mozart's web page: http://mozart.github.io/. An answer was posted, why was this closed?

Answer (score 4):

The official website of Mozart suggests installing the package mozart, mozart-doc and mozart-stdlib from the Ubuntu Software Center. But here is the whole enchilada.
[As per Ubuntu wiki:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mozart)

Installing Mozart 1.4.0

Installation Instructions for Ubuntu 64-bit

The official website of Mozart suggests installing the package `mozart`, `mozart-doc` and `mozart-stdlib` from the Ubuntu Software Center. Don't do that if you're running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu. These packages are broken for this architecture.

Instead, follow the instructions below

1. Install the "ia32-libs" package, the 32-bit "libx11-6" package (i.e. "libx11-6:i386"), the 32-bit "libgmp10" package (i.e. "libgmp10:i386") and GNU/Emacs.
2. Download this deb file.
3. Open your file manager (i.e. Nautilus) and double click on the downloaded file. It will open it with the Ubuntu Software Center. If it does not, right click on the file and choose "Open With Other Application..." and then select the Ubuntu Software Center.
4. The Ubuntu Software Center will say "Only install this file if you trust the origin.", this is normal. Click the Install button, authenticate as asked and wait for the installation to proceed. If it complains about dependency problem, check that you have correctly done the point 1. of the section Installation Instructions for Ubuntu 64-bit of this wiki.

   To install the remaining part of the Mozart standard library, install the `mozart-stdlib` package. You can also get the doc by installing the `mozart-doc` package.

Installation Instructions for Ubuntu 32-bit

Warning: if you are using a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, see the appropriate section above !

As suggested by the official website of Mozart, simply install the `mozart` package and the `mozart-stdlib` package. You can also get the doc by installing the `mozart-doc` package.

Troubleshooting

Graphics Engine (tk.exe) crashed or could not be started

If you get the following error message

Graphics Engine (tk.exe) crashed or could not be started

when launching Mozart. That's maybe because you are missing one of the three 32-bit packages you had to install. So check you have installed the "ia32-libs" package, the 32-bit `libx11-6` package (i.e. `libx11-6:i386`) and 32-bit `libgmp10` package (i.e. `libgmp10:i386`).

However, even if you do that, you may still end up with the same problem. If you go to: `/usr/lib/mozart/platform/unknown-unknown$` and type: `linux32 ./tk.exe` and you get something like

```
./tk.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libtk8.4.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

That means tk.exe is still finding the wrong arch library. I managed to fix it by making a symbolic link in `/usr/lib/mozart/platform/unknown-unknown/lib` to the libraries installed by this package in `/usr/lib32`. Hope this helps, it worked for me.

Could not link module

If you get an error like the following

```
%********************** Error: module manager *******************
%**
%** Could not link module
%**
%** Could not load functor at URL: x-oz://system/wp/QTk.ozf
%**--------------------------------------------------------------
```

you are likelly to be missing some part of the Mozart standard library. Make sure you have installed the "mozart-stdlib" package as recommended above.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to do that too?

Comment: 32bit or 64? was there a particular part if the official instructions (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mozart) that troubled you?

Comment: No, it's just better to include as much vital information as possible in your answer ;) If you could provide instructions for both architectures it would be awesome!

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the tip. Is cut,copy,paste considered bad form? The community docs are pretty strait forward.

Comment: Copy and pasting is acceptable from some sources (i.e. the Ubuntu Wiki), just make sure you cite your references.